# Copy only distinct to second array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to copy an array to another one that only copies what is distinct. I had this working before I was doing a multi dim array. Now when I run the following code it just copies the original array to the second array. I also need to keep them in an array format as I output the data on a webpage later on. What am I doing wrong or can I not do this with multi dim?

```
string[][] array;
string[][] array2;
array2 = array.Distinct().ToArray();
```

After posting this can I edit my file.readalllines to not read lines that are the same? The code is below and table gets passed back as array.

```
 string[][] table = File.ReadAllLines(@path)
                       .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: When you say not working what do you mean? And when you want to do `Distinct()` do you want that each inner array will have only distinct values? Will be good to show some input and expected data

Comment: `Distinct` is not defined for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Imagine that you have `array == {"a", "b", "a", "d"}, {"a", "b", "c", "b"}`; what is the expected answer?

Comment: You need to first define what distinct means in this scenario.  And what you expect .NET to do for you.

Comment: Do you have lines that are duplicated or do you have in this `line.Split(';')` duplicated items that you want to distinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity. Why not use this (apply distinct on line level):

```
 string[][] table = File.ReadAllLines(@path)
                   .Distinct()
                   .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
                   .ToArray();
```

The assumption is here, that equal lines lead to the same array. That means, the order is a component in the definition of equality of two different lines.

Comment: That's what I was doing wrong. I had a feeling I could read it in and tried something like this previously. My issue was I was trying .Distinct().ToArray(); on the last line. Thank you.

Comment: If you think that this is about getting distinct values in a CSV like fashion, then this would likely to fail. Two lines might have the same exact data with the exception of trailing space for a < field >.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - You are absolutely right. Therefore I have included the assumption in the answer.

Comment: Yes but that is not what I meant. Consider two lines as: <1 ;'Name1'; 100> and <1;'Name1'   ;100>. From a data file parsing viewpoint, those lines have the same data.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: What if the file contains lines `"1;2"` and `"2;1"`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Then they are different. But I see your point, that for a general solution the definition for "what is different" has to be made. It is to the OP to decide, if the assumption holds, that textual different lines leads to logically distinct arrays.

Answer (score 1):

(I think my comment was not understood at all, so adding an answer)

Consider your text file was like this (c:\temp\myFile.txt):

```
1; Name1; 100
1; Name1;100
1 ;Name1;100
11; Name1; 100
2;Name2;20
```

Then you can get distinct rows with a code like:

```
void Main()
{
    int custId;
    decimal amount;
    var content =
      File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\myFile.txt")
      .Select(f => f.Split(';'))
      .Select(f => new
      {
          CustomerID = int.TryParse(f[0], out custId) ? custId : -1,
          Company = f[1].Trim(),
          Amount = Decimal.TryParse(f[2], out amount) ? amount : 0M
      })
      .Where(f => f.CustomerID != -1)
      .Distinct();

    foreach (var c in content)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CustomerID:{0}, Company:{1}, Amount:{2}", c.CustomerID, c.Company, c.Amount);
    }  
}
```